# Django and apache2 restart

Tags: python, django, apache2, virtualhost

I have the following issue as I'm trying to setup Django with apache:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
[Wed Mar 07 03:21:17 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting [Wed Mar 07 03:21:18 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
   ...done.
```

Any ideas what could cause this?

Here is the contents of the `sites-available` file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

              <VirtualHost *:80>
              ServerAdmin admin@website.com
              ServerName www.website.com
              ServerAlias website.com

              Alias /static /home/website/store/static

              DocumentRoot /home/website/store
              WSGIScriptAlias / /home/website/store/apache/django.wsgi

              ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

              LogLevel warn
              CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
              </VirtualHost>
```

Also here is the wsgi file:

```
import os, sys

#path to directory of the .wsgi file ('apache/')
wsgi_dir= os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

#path to project root directory (parent of 'apache/')
project_dir=os.path.dirname(wsgi_dir)

#add project directory to system's PATH
sys.path.append(project_dir)

project_settings=os.path.join(project_dir,'settings')
os.envision['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='store.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application=django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is with Apache and has nothing to do with django.

If you are doing development you don't need apache. Use the [built in development server](http://django.me/runserver) for your needs.

Since you are on a debian based system, see [this article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412) which explains the correct way to set up multiple hosts on debian (its the same if you are on other debian-based systems like the various ubuntu flavors). If you want more information on virtual hosts (which you should read anyway), the [virtual host documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) has many examples.

Answer (score 0):

From memory this is caused by having NameVirtualHost for same value in multiple places in Apache configuration. Usually you wouldn't have the directive in a site file in sites-available directory as would already exist for port 80 in separate part of Apache configuration.